# Multiple Column Form with Form Builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

Is there anyway to have a **multi-column form** using **Form Builder package**, or any other alternative. I dont want to use native forms as it may not be a cleaner option to display 10-20 questions.

Something like this..

[image]

Comment: Why may not be a cleaner option to use native forms?

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will produce issue